# Printing 2d Array in Matrix form

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So my code properly prints a matrix with equal dimensions (3x3, 2x2) but not unequal ones like a 3x2. What is wrong with the loop?

```
  public Matrix(int d[][])
{
    numRows = d.length; // d.length is the number of 1D arrays in the 2D array
    if(numRows == 0)
        numColumns = 0;
    else
        numColumns = d[0].length; // d[0] is the first 1D array
    data = new int[numRows][numColumns]; // create a new matrix to hold the data
    // copy the data over
    for(int i=0; i < numRows; i++) 
        for(int j=0; j < numColumns; j++)
            data[i][j] = d[i][j];
}

public String toString()
{
String doPrint="";
      Matrix k = this;
      Matrix l = new Matrix(new int[k.numRows][k.numColumns]);
      for (int i = 0; i < l.numColumns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < l.numRows; j++) 
            doPrint = doPrint + k.data[i][j]+" ";
      doPrint = doPrint + "\n";
      }
        return doPrint;
     }
```

Comment: show output you got, and the expected output

Comment: @DavidWallace forget it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing the index used in the nested `for` loop of the method `toString()`.

You are using `i` for rows and `j` for columns in:

```
doPrint = doPrint + k.data[i][j] + " ";
```

but in the loops you have swapped the indices. You should first loop through rows, and then through columns:

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.numRows; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < l.numColumns; j++)
```

Comment: isn't that what I said ? :)

Answer (score 0):

in the first one you have:

So my code properly prints a matrix with equal dimensions (3x3, 2x2) but not unequal ones like a 3x2. What is wrong with the loop?

```
 for(int i=0; i < numRows; i++) 
    for(int j=0; j < numColumns; j++)
        data[i][j] = d[i][j];
```

and in the second

```
for (int i = 0; i < l.numColumns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < l.numRows; j++) 
        doPrint = doPrint + k.data[i][j]+" ";
```

they are not matching :) (rows to columns)